# Activation of virtual environment for python in PowerShell the parenthesis not showing does it matter when shell confirms env is on?

Tags: python, django, powershell, visual-studio-code, pipenv

My PowerShell virtual environment activates the virtual environment for my Django project but does not show the parenthesis does it really matter. `C:\Users\xxx\.virtualenvs\mb-g7VMb0x7 already activated`. I cannot use `Scripts\activate` as I installed my virtualenv using `pipenv` not `virtualenv -p python .` which normal carry the scripts folder. On my Vscode  the parenthesis shows that I am in a virtual environment `(mb) PS E:\Dev\mb`.

Comment: Just to clarify: You're asking if the absence of a prefix such as `(mb)` _from the PowerShell prompt string_ indicates a problem?

Comment: It doesn't indicate a problem because when I run  ```sys.executable```  its shows I am in a virtual environment. I simply wanted to know how to activate the prefix

Comment: It would really help if you could rewrite your post and its title to clearly state your question. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips.

Answer (score 0):

It works well on my computer, could you provide a screenshot of it?

`pipenv` environment has a `Script` folder that contains activate function, such as

```
& C:/Users/Administrator/.virtualenvs/Administrator-S9WHhKuh/Scripts/Activate.ps1
```

in the following picture:

[image]

Update:

[image]

Comment: I am still a below points to be allowed to put a screen shot but I have loaded the outcome

Answer (score 0):

How do I activate in my PowerShell or Bash terminals the prefix to show. I am in a virtual environment if I run `sys.python` it will show I am in a virtual environment.

```
xxx@DESKTOP-TL9TTEG MINGW64 /e/works/mslearn-django-views-templates/starter (main)
$ python
Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:43:08) [MSC v.1926 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.executable)
C:\Users\xxx\.virtualenvs\starter-Nf07b0Gm\Scripts\python.exe
>>> exit()
xxx@DESKTOP-TL9TTEG MINGW64 /e/works/mslearn-django-views-templates/starter (main)
```

Whereas in my Vscode editor the prefix shows that I am in a virtual environment.

```
PS E:\works\mslearn-django-views-templates\starter> & C:/Users/xxx/.virtualenvs/starter-Nf07b0Gm/Scripts/Activate.ps1
(starter) PS E:\works\mslearn-django-views-templates\starter>
```

Will this affect the final output of my project

Comment: hi, sorry for late, it works well on my computer, you can check the update in my answer. If you directly run & C:/Users/xxx/.virtualenvs/starter-Nf07b0Gm/Scripts/Activate.ps1 in your PowerShell, what will happen? Have you add the python path of the virtual environment in your environment path? You can get your environment path through this command in your powershell: $env:path